# Set Value to ComboBoxItem smartgwt

Tags: java, smartgwt

In drop down I get like this. find image attached. Actually in coulmn of "Name" field both 'Name' and 'Description' are displaying as comma(,) separated.

```
final ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem("attributeTypeId","Attr. Type");
ListGridField nameField = new ListGridField("name", "Name");
ListGridField descField = new ListGridField("description","Description");
descField.setShowHover(true);
comboBoxItem.setPickListFields(nameField, descField);
comboBoxItem.setPickListWidth(200);
comboBoxItem.setFilterLocally(true);
comboBoxItem.setColSpan(2);
comboBoxItem.setAddUnknownValues(false);
comboBoxItem.setValueField(FieldNames.ID_FIELD);
comboBoxItem.setDisplayField(FieldNames.NAME_FIELD);
comboBoxItem.setAutoFetchData(true);

 OptionListDataSource attrTypeds = OptionListDataSource.getInstance(FieldNames.ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_FIELD);
 attrTypeds.fetchData(null, new DSCallback() {
 @Override 
 public void execute(final DSResponse response, final Object rawData, final DSRequest request) { 

 Record[] recList = response.getData();
 LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> dataLinkMap = new inkedHashMap<String,String[]>(); //LinkedHashMap<String,

 dataLinkMap.put("0", new String[]{"Select",""}); 
 for (Record record : recList) {

 String attrId = record.getAttribute(FieldNames.ID_FIELD); 
 String attrName = record.getAttribute(FieldNames.NAME_FIELD); 
 String attrDesc = record.getAttribute(FieldNames.DESCRIPTION_FIELD);

 dataLinkMap.put(attrId, new String[]{attrName,attrDesc});
 }
  comboBoxItem.setValueMap(dataLinkMap);
  } 
  });
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8VOp.png)

Comment: You mention you want to display Name and Description, but your code makes no attempt to use Description. Do you want to use all 3 fields then, or just ID and Name?

Comment: @carlossierra , I need to set all three fields, but Name and Description will be displayed

Comment: did you see the edit to my answer? I think it answers your question for v3 of SmartGWT...

Comment: @carlossierra  method `getRecords()` of `DSResponse` is from v5, In your answer you mentioned about formatting, where i need to apply it?

Comment: no, it's not. You really need to read carefully both the [server's DSResponse API](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-3.1/server/javadoc/com/isomorphic/datasource/DSResponse.html#getRecords()) and my answer.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code to achieve what I understand you want to achieve:

```
public class TestCases implements EntryPoint {  

    public void onModuleLoad() {  
        DataSource logDS = DataSource.get("yourDSName");  

        final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();  
        form.setWidth(550);  
        form.setNumCols(2);  

        ListGridField nameField = new ListGridField(FieldNames.NAME_FIELD);  
        ListGridField descriptionField = new ListGridField(FieldNames.NAME_DESCRIPTION);  

        LinkedHashMap<String,String> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();  
        hashMap.put("-1", "Select"); 

        ComboBoxItem myItem = new ComboBoxItem();  
        myItem.setTitle("ComboBox");  
        myItem.setOptionDataSource(logDS);  
        myItem.setDisplayField("category");  
        myItem.setValueField(FieldNames.ID_FIELD);  
        myItem.setSpecialValues(hashMap);
        myItem.setPickListWidth(300);  
        myItem.setPickListFields(nameField, descriptionField);  

        form.setItems(myItem);  
        form.draw();  
    }  
}
```

Notice:

- In order to display various fields, you need to use setPickListFields with the reference to those fields.
- You don't need to call `fetch()` on the `DataSource` itself. This is done automatically for you when you use DataBound components like `ComoBoxItem`.
- You can add additional *empty* values using `setSpecialValues()` without modifying your `DSResponse` data (which is why you don't need to use `fetch()` directly).

**EDIT**

The problem you are having is that the `ValueMap`, which is just a `Map` (in other words, just a group of key/value pairs), that you are providing to the `ComboBoxItem` is not the same as the `Record[]` object provided directly by the `DataSource`, which in essence is just a List made of several `Map`s, each representing a field name and its value. This way, besides the value field, you can provide several fields to the ComboBoxItem for display purposes, like  Name and Description, in your particular case.

From looking at the API, it looks to me that you can't provide a `Record[]` manually to the `ComboBoxItem`, so either you get the data via DMI (which for me is the easiest) or other method that allows you to modify and return the required response from the server automatically to the ComboBoxItem by using the data binding capabilities, or you stick to showing just the "values" (which is what you are getting right now, but off course you could format the data better).

What I mean with formatting is that if you choose to go with your original approach of using `setValueMap()`, you need to provide a `Map` where each entry in the `Map` is just a value on the ComboBoxItem and its respective display "text", which can be any String combining the values of several other fields, and formatted as desired using String concatenation (for instance, you could make it

```
nameField + ": " + descriptionField
```

But this is as good as it gets with this approach.

Now, via a DMI you would need to define the server class that would provide the properly-formatted data in you datasource descriptor (ds.xml file):

```
<operationBindings>  
    <operationBinding operationType="fetch" serverMethod="fetchComboBoxData">  
        <serverObject  lookupStyle="new" className="com.myApp.ComboBoxDMI"/>  
    </operationBinding>          
</operationBindings>
```

And then create the class and method to provide what you need:

```
public class ComboBoxDMI {

    public DSResponse fetchComboBoxData(DSRequest dsRequest) throws Exception {         
        DSResponse response = dsRequest.execute();
        if (response.statusIsSuccess()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Map<String, Object>> recList = response.getRecords();
            List<Map<String, Object>> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
            // Add here the new record... for each field in your DataSource, you need to set a Map
            // with the key being the field name and the value being the field value. So you need
            // 1 Map entry per field. All your Map entries form 1 record, and that's what you add
            // to your List of Maps
            return constructDSResponse(comboBoxList);
        }
        return response;
    }

    private DSResponse constructDSResponse(List<Map<String, Object>> comboBoxList) {
        DSResponse response = new DSResponse();
        int totalRows = comboBoxList.size();
        response.setStartRow(totalRows > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        response.setEndRow(totalRows);
        response.setTotalRows(totalRows);
        response.setData(comboBoxList);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can follow the original approach I suggest in my original answer, but now you don't need to use the `setSpecialValues` API, which your version doesn't support.

Comment: I want to display name and description field, and id field is value field. When directly setting 'setOptionDataSource' I get desire ouput. but when I alter `DataSource` I didn't get desire result. `setSpecialValues(hashMap)` I can't use as my smartgwt is of 3.0 version. I tried below approach, it seems working but formatting is not showing properly. Please find below my answer and let me know what i am missing.